# Puppeteer: How do I open a page in a new window?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to open a new page in a new window without launching another instance of Puppeteer (i.e. I am *not* trying to run `puppeteer.launch()` multiple times, as this would create another browser session). Is there a way I can open a new window with `browser.newPage()` or some other method from an existing browser session?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why you are avoiding using `puppeteer.launch()`.

but you can do it with `await page.evaluate(()=>window.open("url", "window name", "width=200,height=100"));`
and then find the new `page` object withe `browser.target()`

Comment: As @jameslk stated `puppeteer.launch()` launches browser with a new context. For example I need to test [my Chrome extension](https://github.com/dvdvdmt/popup-tab-switcher) in case of two opened windows and I can't do that with `puppeteer.launch()` because it opens browser with a copy of extension that knows nothing about the same extension in other window.

Comment: And your approach for creating a new window opens a popup window without tabs. I wonder if there is a way to specify the same context to the `puppeteer.launch()`, then it would solve my problem.